# Using Globalnavigation twice in Master Page

Tags: navigation

In my Master Page I want to show the global navigation

It wil look like this:

-> Header (globalnavigation)

-> Breadcrumb

-> Content

-> Footer (globalnavigation)

I want to reuse the globalnavigation in the footer. Is this possible?

Edit:
Thanks to Dandroid:
Just changed the ID's, like this:

```
              <SharePoint:AspMenu
                  ID="TopNavigationMenuV5"
                  Runat="server"
                  EnableViewState="false"
                  DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
                  AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%>"
                  UseSimpleRendering="true"
                  UseSeparateCss="false"
                  Orientation="Horizontal"
                  StaticDisplayLevels="2"
                  MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0"
                  SkipLinkText=""
                  CssClass="s4-tn"/>

            <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TopNavigationDataSource2" Id="topNavigationDelegate2"><Template_Controls>
                        <asp:SiteMapDataSource
                          ShowStartingNode="False"
                          SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider"
                          id="topSiteMap2"
                          runat="server"
                          StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002"/>
                </Template_Controls>
            </SharePoint:DelegateControl>
```

Comment: Could you please explain how to achieve it?

Comment: Rename the ID's and it will work.

example:
<SharePoint:AspMenu      ID="TopNavigationMenuV5"  <---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Just remember to give them seperate IDs. You can you use the same datasource.